# How to use Green's theorem if the divergence is $0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

I'm trying to use Green's theorem to calculate the flux of $F$ through some curve. However, is it possible to use Green's theorem if the divergence of $F$ is $0$?

[image: Green's theorem]

Comment: Why do you think it may not be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course. That means you're integrating $0$ over some area, the result of that is $0$, so the flux through the curve is $0$. Be careful that the divergence is defined at *each point* inside the curve.

Comment: To use Green's theorem, I closed the given curve by drawing a line segment between the two endpoints. To calculate the flux of the original curve, would I just subtract the flux of the line segment from 0, which is the flux of the original curve + the line segment?

Comment: @Math3983 If the divergence of a field is $0$ everywhere, then the flux through any curve between two given end points is the same. So the flux through your complicated curve is equal to the flux through the straight line. This is the same as saying that the flux through the curve, minus the flux through the straight line (which amounts to the fluz into or out of the enclosed area) is $0$.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you.